# Azure SQL Server - How cost will be calculated

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, price, azure-sql-server, bacpac

I have created SQL Server resource in SQL Server and then using import database option, I created database using local [bacpac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database?view=sql-server-2017) file.

I was able to perform this action and my database was created in SQL Server. I looked at Azure SQL pricing but not very much clear on how much cost would be incurred with this approach.

I followed up [this link](https://www.sqlshack.com/import-sample-bacpac-file-azure-sql-database/) to create SQL Server and import database.

As we are doing POC, we would like to know the cost per month with this approach. Also would like to know if I am done with my POC then I need to delete database as well as server from Azure Resources or deleting database will do?

[image: Azure Sql server cost]

Comment: It says right there: $991/mo. Azure is billed by the minute, so if you have it set to this size for 6 hours (for example) then it will cost you $7.99 `(6 / (24 * 31)) * $991 == $7.99`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was aware about hourly cost, my question was related to cost with this approach, where i need to Add SQL server and then SQL DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Database DTU-model is calculated per hour, the cost of each hour is based on the highest tier assigned to the database on each hour. You won't pay for incoming traffic to Azure SQL and importing a database from on-premises in terms of traffic will have no cost. On [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/single/) URL you will find a price calculator that may help you perform cost estimation, there you should select "Single database" and based on the image you shared above you should select the DTU-model.

If the applications that will use your databases are not located on the same region/data center then you should consider on your POC an estimation of monthly costs for bandwidth consumption. See bandwidth pricing information [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/).

Take in consideration also that enable some features for your Azure SQL Database like Advanced Threat Detection, Azure Logs (OMS) and Long-Term Backup Retention may increase costs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OK
so in all case cost will be based on DTU and does not matter which approach i.e. [1] Create DB directly with SQL database [2] Add SQL server and then Add database in it
Correct ?. 
Also can you please let me know about my question related to whether i need to delete SQL server & SQL databse or deleting DB will do ?

Comment: You just need to delete the database. Azure SQL Database servers are logical servers

Comment: If you do not like the predefined  set of computing power that comes with the DTU model and would like to have more granular control over storage and CPU resources, then consider using vCore model.